# How to get user input to choose a shape for pyramid python

Tags: python, while-loop

So im currently stuck on a step, the questions states that we want a users input for the shape of the pyramid and the height.

So far I have this as my code.

```py
shape_input = input("shape?: ")
while shape_input not in {"pyramid, square, triangle"}:
    try:
        shape_input = input("shape?: ")
    except EOFError:
        break
return shape_input
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that

```py
while shape_input not in {"pyramid, square, triangle"}:
```

checks whether the input is in a set of one object---the string "pyramid, square, triangle", whereas you mean:

```
while shape_input not in {"pyramid", "square", "triangle"}:
```

Well done on use of a set though.

P.S. On the UI front, I would change the message inside the loop to something like "Invalid shape, try again:".  You need to feed back in general what is going on your program: in this case, they need to re-enter because they haven't entered correctly (so they need to be told that).